# XCode keeps creating not needed signing profiles

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile, ad-hoc-distribution

To do an adhoc distribution of an app in development I have manually created the app's ID, separated development and distribution profiles which include only those devices I'm going to distribute to. Then, in the Code Signing section of the Build Settings I manually set that specific development profile instead of  set by default. I've built the app and tried to export it for adhoc.

On my first attempt xcode started complaining that it cannot find any valid profile including ALL! devices listed in my account. On the second attempt it has automatically created distribution profile with ALL devices listed in and signed my app with it. At some point it has also created development profile with all devices in.

I tried to remove those profiles, then all profiles at all, recreate, manually download and install specific profiles, nothing helped. XCode keeps creating profiles which I don't need and signs with them.

I'll greatly appreciate thoughts on how to stop it and sign my app with what I want to sign it.

Comment: What is your concern with having more devices in the profile? Having the extra devices won't hurt anything, unless you are trying to use the provisioning profiles to limit the apps from running on unapproved devices (something I wouldn't recommend, as MDM would be a better solution to that problem).

Comment: :) Well, I'm concerned with xcode which decides what is better for me. I just want to use profiles I created manually, why I cannot?
To limit the apps from running on unapproved devices is exactly what I want use different profiles for. Please, tell me why you wouldn't recommend this and what is MDM, thank you.

Comment: If you truly want to manage profiles manually (which is what we do, simply remove your apple developer account from Xcode.  If you're not using it to manage you profiles, certificates, etc, you might as well not be signed in. MDM is mobile device management - and it provides ways to prevent what gets installed on devices, although what you probably need would be MAM (mobile application management) which is management of apps, not management of devices.